# Where should I ask "X"?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation, scope

If I'm not sure what Stack Exchange site to ask a question on, what's the recommended protocol? Do I ask the meta-question here on meta.stackoverflow.com? It looks like there are several "Where should I ask..." questions here, and the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) doesn't really cover this area.

Comment: This is tough, as it's unlikely that any single person is sufficiently versed in what's on-topic at every SE site to be able to direct every question.

Comment: @Gabe But it's not all that unlikely that somebody visiting meta might recognize that a question belongs on a site they frequent, or at least be able to point the asker to a site-specific meta for clarification.

Comment: Alternatively, ask in the place that *seems* most proper to you. If it doesn't belong there, it'll get migrated elsewhere. That's really what migration is designed for; it was never intended as an insult to the asker whose question gets migrated.

Comment: Some questions, of course don't fit any site - 3d graphics seems to be one (unless a new SE's come along I'm not aware of?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asking here is fine. As I mentioned in my comment, either somebody will be able to give you a definitive answer, or at least will point you to a site-specific meta if it's hard to tell 100% if your question would belong on that site. You can then get further clarification there if needed.

We even have a tag dedicated to this entire concept; tag your question here with [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec)!

Comment: 2 upvotes, so it's fine but not really good? Also Jeff's answer, which is the opposite, also got 2 upvotes only? Hmmmm....

Comment: @Yar Both approaches are good. You can follow Jeff's advice and if you're still not sure where to post the question, follow mine. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'd start by browsing the directory:

https://stackexchange.com/sites

There's a fairly succinct definition of each site there.

While there are some grey areas of overlap between sites (the example I always use is URL rewriting questions, which could be on SO, SF, or even Webmasters), it's not too difficult to resolve by asking yourself *"what's my job title"* or *"what professional hat do I usually wear?"* and ask it of that community.

In other words, if you have a question about motorcycles, you don't start yelling out your question on crowded street corners hoping someone will answer. You go to the place where motorcyclists hang out, first...

Comment: Thanks, that helps me. Yet you should consider: Not always is ones question related to ones job (title) or profession!! It may be a hobby, it may be a new (!) industry or job or entrepreneurial venture that one might want to start. So with this lack of knowledge, it sure might be not so easy to decide! Additionally, if the question is on the vicinity of several topics or at an overlapping intersection (like the circles forming SE!), what is one supposed to do?