# Please link to Stack Exchange Directory on footer of each SE site

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, footer

Please put the link to the [Stack Exchange directory](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page at the bottom of every SE site.

With increasing frequency I find myself wondering **Where do I ask *"Where do I ask ...?"* ?**. The stack exchange network is large enough that I don't know all the rooms, and new ones continue to be added. My question is already here in the form of [Where should I ask "X"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90225/where-should-i-ask-x), but I didn't locate that question, and the answer of "look in the directory" until after I'd spent 15 or 20 minutes searching for and composing my own question.

I did look at the short directory in the footer of every site first, but I know it's only a partial list, and being a big long non-alphabetized list of words it's hard to mentally parse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't help but notice the (defunct) Shop is still linked in the footer. How about replacing it with a "(more) sites"/"network"/etc link?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, agreed!**

There is getting to be too many different sites in the footer now for the list to be useful. You can't scan the list easily, and it's difficult to locate the link to the site you want, even if you know the name/topic.

Moreover, as pointed out in the question, beta sites don't appear in the footer on fully-launched sites (and vice versa), so it can be difficult to tell if there might be a site elsewhere on the network that is an even better fit for your question and/or interests.

Besides, someone spent a lot of time on the new Stack Exchange home page design, and [the grid view of all the sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) is so beautiful that it would be a shame not to have more people see it!