# Shop link still present on SO and Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, shop, footer

The SE shop is still linked in the sites' footer even though it is now defunct.

Is this intentional?

Comment: Nice catch.  Good thing no one ever looks there.

Comment: @jadarnel yeah. I just happened by there because on the ipad, it is faster to use the footer links than to enter the url

Comment: Aw man! Is my SO t-shirt going to become a valuable collectible?

Comment: The shop will probably get more traffic in the next 10 minutes than it has in the past 10 weeks.

Comment: Related: [Please link to Stack Exchange Directory on footer of each SE site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126715/139726#139726)

Comment: What!? No more shop!? I finally get a source of income and you take away the things I'd want to spend it on!?

Comment: Huh. Since there's a password field there, I thought they were keeping the page up for giveaway/contest winners. How sad.

Comment: @PopularDemand no, there are still giveaway/contest things, but they don't go through the store

Comment: @BenBrocka yeah, but... that's boring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, that link will disappear in the next build.

Comment: Feel free to delete this then